# How to unmarshall JSON into protobuff with different-case fields?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Coming from Python. I need to unmarshal a JSON into a protobuff message. Something like:

```
{"jobId": "abc"}
```

I defined my proto files field exactly the same, hoping for an easy match up during message contruction:

```
string jobId = 1;
```

Protobuff changes the fields names into CamelCase. Thus when I am trying to unmarshal I receive the error:

```golang
  10     msg := &Message{}
  11     err := protojson.Unmarshal([]byte(MessageData), msg)

>> msg.jobId undefined (type *Message has no field or method jobId, but does have JobId)
```

What is a clean way to achieve this? i.e. preferring no external dependencies, and if not, preferring no bespoke wrangling.

Please note that I am already using `protojson`.

**EDIT**:

In Python, `google.protobuf.json_format.Parse` does this: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py#L403

Comment: Couldn't replicate with [this proto](https://pastebin.com/Pxmaechp) and [this go code](https://pastebin.com/qQHjZDKW). No error, output is [here](https://pastebin.com/3Bt57HY2)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and worked fine. I will explain how I have done this.

my `message.proto` file as below. This is contained in proto-test directory as

```
myProject
 |
 +-- main.go
 |    
 +-- proto-test
 |  |  
 |  +-- message.proto
```

```
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package = "/proto_msg";

package proto_msg;

message Message {
    string jobId = 1;
    bool sentOnce = 2;
}
```

After I have run the proto command inside the proto-test directory to make the go file relevant to the `message.proto` `message.pb.go` file is created inside the `proto_msg` directory with the `proto_msg` go package.

**Command**: `protoc -I=. --go_out=. ./message.proto`

```
myProject
 |
 +-- main.go
 |    
 +-- proto-test
 |  |  
 |  +-- message.proto
 |  +-- proto_msg
 |     |
 |     +--message.pb.go
```

Ans created Go message struct as below.

```
type Message struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    JobId    string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=jobId,proto3" json:"jobId,omitempty"`
    SentOnce bool   `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=sentOnce,proto3" json:"sentOnce,omitempty"`
}
```

then after I have run the following main code.

```
package main

import (
    msg "myProject/proto-test/proto_msg"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    m := &msg.Message{}
    MessageData := `{"jobId": "abc", "sentOnce": true}`

    err := protojson.Unmarshal([]byte(MessageData), m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(m.String())
}
```

It ran successfully and output is

```
jobId:"abc" sentOnce:true
```

Comment: Since this is an answer to the question, could you please elaborate on how does the fact that the code works for you (great examples by the way) answers to why it doesn't work for the topic starter?